# Django Template _set.all

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have this model:

```
class CustomerAddresses(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    CustomerID = models.ForeignKey('Customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I render the Address Data in my Template:

```
% for address in customer_default_shipping_address %}
                                        {% if address.Address_Company %}
                                            <h5>{{ address.Address_Company }}<br/>
                                            {{ address.Address_Firstname }} {{ address.Address_Lastname }}</h5>
                                        {% else %}
                                             <h5>{{ address.Address_Firstname }} {{ address.Address_Lastname }}</h5>
                                        {% endif %}

                                    <address class="mb-0 font-14 address-lg">
                                        {{ address.Street}}<br>
                                        {{ address.Zip}} {{ address.City}}<br>
                                        {% for customer in address.customers_set.all %}
                                            <abbr title="Telefon">P:</abbr> {{ customer.PhoneNumber }} <br/>
                                            <abbr title="E-Mail">M:</abbr> {{ customer.Email }}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </address>
                                    {% endfor %}
```

but the E-Mail and Phone Field will not be rendered, are I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your relational model is wrong. A `CustomerAddress` only has one `CustomerID` linked to it because of the `ForeignKey` usage, thus you cannot look through `address.customes_set.all`.

Give it a go without the second nested loop and have just: `address.customerID.PhoneNumber` for example.